# Can I configure a DataDog integration inside docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: datadog

Lets assume I am running a containerised environment, and I want to use the datadog ping integration (https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/ping/).
I have my standard docker-compose.yml file, where I install datadog following the official guide (https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/docker/?tab=standard). No problem so far.

Now, if I want to use the Ping integration, if I am not wrong, I have to:

- First, install the integration, executing form host: *docker-compose exec datadog agent integration install -t -r datadog-ping==1.0.2*
- Second, configure the integration. So I have to SSH to the docker container, install **inetutils-ping** package, and create a file */etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/ping.d/conf.yaml* from https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-extras/blob/master/ping/datadog_checks/ping/data/conf.yaml.example, with the configuration we want.

Once I am done, I can check from host that the check is up and running (*docker-compose exec datadog agent status*), and I can see data on DataDog.

At this point, everything works as expected.

My question: **Is there any way from docker-compose.yml file to install and configure this integration?** May be using DataDog variables, or something similar? Or is it something that we have to do it “manually”?

Thanks!

Comment: Put your startup script in the appropriate dockerfile rather than in `docker-compose.yml`. Then you can use `entrypoint` and `cmd` to pass vars.